Why can't I solve $\int y' y'' dx$ changing the order of diff and integration?
I know that in order to solve: $\int y'  y'' dx$
I can do $dy' = y''dx$, which is the same as subing $u=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $du=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}  dx$ which results in:
$\int y' dy' = \frac {y'^2}{2} + C$
Why can't I do $dy = y'dx$ for:
$\int y'' dy = \int d^2y/dx^2 dy = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\int y dy) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\frac {y^2}{2}) = y'^2+y y''$?

The integrand still depends on $x$ in a way, so you cannot just remove it.

A major problem is that derivative cannot interchange with the indefinite integral. For example consider $y=x$, then $$\displaystyle\int y''dy=\text{constant}\quad \text{but}\quad\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\displaystyle\int ydy=1$$
One can see LHS gives a family of functions, but RHS will always return a single value. In general they cannot be equal, so your method $2$ cannot hold unfortunately.

I also noticed that one gives a family, the other only a particular solution, but I was puzzled by it, so differentiantion under the integral sign, or the feynman trick can only work cause they work with difinite integrals?

@EdryssonRocha Yes. In my opinion, indefinite integral is just an less-abstract presentation to write down the set of all antiderivatives of a function. In short, the indefinite integral itself is not a function, so it makes no sense to differentiate a set with respect to $\alpha$.
